# SonarQube report for both c# and JS files in single project with module approach?

Tags: c#, javascript, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Can I use SonarQube to analyze my project which is in .net C# and has extensive use of javascripts (around 10 javascript files). I mean can i get a report for both c# and JS files?
I tried module approach as listed here in  [SonarQube documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner) but didn't succeed.

Comment: You need to show some code of what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported for .NET. You'll have to run two separate analyses. You can aggregate the results with the Views plugin: http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/

Comment: Are there any changes to analyzing a .NET C# project and JS in one TFS build definition?